# import c++ structure to vb with dll

Tags: c++, vb.net, string, dll, struct

I'm having trouble with importing strings to VB from c++

I have my structure and export function declared like this in c++:

```
struct test
{
    LPSTR text;
};
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) test Func()
{
    LPSTR text;
    text = (LPSTR) "JUST TESTING";
    test str;
    str.text = text;
    return str;
}
```

I'm importing this Func() function to VB I do "surprisingly" succeed with this text:

```
<DllImport("dlltest.dll", EntryPoint:="Func", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function AddFunction() As String
    End Function
```

In this case, AddFunction() returns me the string I described in c++ ("JUST TESTING")
But when I try to define my structure in vb, I'm starting to get problems:

```
Public Structure test
   Public t As String
End Structure

<DllImport("dlltest.dll", EntryPoint:="Func", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function AddFunction() As test
    End Function
```

In this case, the program throws a Marshal Directive Exception error every time I 
call the function AddFunction()

```
dim A as test
A = AddFunction()
```

I also tried writing this before defining my test structure

`<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)>`

And this before defining Public t as string

```
_<System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)> _
```

And none of these help. I need to read my string from the structure. I have no problems reading integers the same way in structures. Only these strings. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You will only ever be able to return string literals like this. You should use a better marshalling technique.

Comment: Many unwise things you could do when you use pinvoke, lying about the native declaration is certainly high on that list.  But still booting XP on your dev machine is on the top.  Your hack will crash with an AccessViolation on any later Windows version.  As the pinvoke marshaller *knows* when you don't lie.  Manual marshaling with Marshal.PtrToStructure() is required, not releasing the string is very likely to bomb your program with an OutOfMemoryException, eventually.